# Hide B-Modal component until API call in child component return values

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

In Vue, I have a model view component like this.

## Code

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    ref="modalDialog"
    class="-modal"
    scrollable
    hide-footer
    :title="title"
    :visible="visible"
  >
    <my-second-component
      ref="valueEditor"
      :some-values:some-values
      @no-values="hideDialog"      
    />
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
import MySecondComponent from ...
export default {
  name: 'MyFirstComponent',
  components: { MySecondComponent },
  .....
</script>
```

inside my second component I have

```
  mounted () {
    this.getValues()
  },

  async getValues () {
      try {
        const args = {
          ...
        }
        const response = await this.$api.some(args)
        this.Values = response.count ? response.results : []

        // Close dialog if none found
        if (!this.values.length) {
          this.$emit('no-values')
        }
        ...
      } catch (e) {
        this.onError(e)
      }
    },
```

So when the modal window is opened it renders the second component and this component get data from API - if none are there it closes the modal window with the emitting `no-values`

## Problem:

If there are no values get back from API, the modal window flashes. It opens and then closes quickly. And this is annoying to our customers.

So my question is how to "hide" the b-modal window (but still start the process) so long that the second component wouldn't return if there are any values or not.

### Conditions:

- The Second component is used in multiple places over huge projects. The behavior should not change, nor the implementation unless the default implementation is the same.
- The first component should not be static. There are some property pass into second component. If I set first component to static, than those properties would be set on mount (and undefined) and will not be changed when needed.